# How do I delete or edit a section in Google News?

Tags: google-news

I added a section to Google News with the wrong title/search and now I'd like to delete it or edit it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Google News no longer allows you to add or remove sections, so the answer below is out of date.

For the latest on customizing what you see on Google News, [visit the Google News help site here](https://support.google.com/googlenews/?hl=en#topic=7688382).

---

- Click the 'Manage Sections' pencil icon
- Hover over the mis-titled section and click the 'Delete' trash-can icon
- 'Save' your changes

Comment: This does not appear to work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can't anymore. See here: https://support.google.com/googlenews/thread/704608

> Google News no longer supports customizing news sections. The documentation is unfortunately out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS selector to block the sides.    You can use it in uBlock Origin.  For example here I'm blocking sports and entertainment.

If anyone can help me make a selector for the feed that would be great!

```
##div[aria-label="Sports"]
##div[aria-label="Entertainment"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the other answers, Google News has removed its functionality which previously allowed users to remove news sections.

To block the news sections, you'd have to use a content-blocking browser extension like [**uBlock Origin**](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) (uBO). For example, to block the 'Sports' section, add the following filters as custom filters under the uBO Dashboard → My filters:

```
news.google.com##main > c-wiz > div:first-child > div:has(> div:first-child > h2:only-child:has-text(/^Sports$/))
news.google.com##main > c-wiz > div:first-child > div:has(> div:first-child > h2:only-child:has-text(/^Sports$/))+div
news.google.com##main > c-wiz > div:first-child > div:has(> div:first-child > h2:only-child:has-text(/^Sports$/))+div+div
news.google.com##main > c-wiz > div:first-child > div:has(> div:first-child > h2:only-child:has-text(/^Sports$/))+div+div+div
news.google.com##main > c-wiz > div:first-child > div:has(> div:first-child > h2:only-child:has-text(/^Sports$/))+div+div+div+div
```

To block the 'Entertainment' section, simply replace all instances of 'Sports' in the above filters with 'Entertainment'.

<sup>Filters source: Comment in Reddit /r/uBlockOrigin subreddit post by RraaLL - [Any way to block the entire sports section from Google News?](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/kijyiz/any_way_to_block_the_entire_sports_section_from/)</sup>